Are de-orbiting Starlink satellites a danger to commercial airliners, as FAA has told Congress?
Starlink satellites deorbit at the end of their service live. Once the constellation is fully populated, there will be an average of one an hour "timing out" and deorbiting. https://www.cbc.ca/news/science/satellites-polluting-atmosphere-1.7239899
Many sources claim Starlinks are "demisable" (=burn up completely), but the FAA disagrees. The altitude of peak heating and maxQ do not necessarily correlate with the altitude at which fragments  burn into harmlessly small fragments. Do fragments of a hazardous size penetrate to the cruise altitude of commercial airliners? Th FAA's report to congress says, "Yes,they do." https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/Report_to_Congress_Reentry_Disposal_of_Satellites.pdf

Based on conservative assumptions, a fragment of 300 grams or greater
may cause casualties to aircraft occupants ... roughly 1.65 million people in the air around the
globe ... people in aircraft derive their vulnerability from debris
that either penetrates the fuselage and directly impacts an occupant
or causes an uncontrolled landing of the aircraft. This debris can be
fairly small ... threshold for aircraft downing objects is roughly 300
grams ... the SpaceX spacecraft could each produce three pieces of
debris of 300 grams ...
Payload reentries are expected to continue to grow to roughly ten
thousand per year if the Starlink constellation's operational lifetime
follows the announced operational lifetimes of 5years. Risks to people
on the ground and in the air will continue to grow accordingly.
The space industry has not yet collectively met the 90 percent success
rate for satellite post-mission disposal, and even at the 90 percent
rate, over 5,000 satellites could fail in orbit and randomly reenter.
Reentry debris from random reentering objects has differing ballistic
coefficients and masses. This causes the reentering debris to fall in
a very long reentry footprint.
Most reentry breakup events occur between 80 kilometers and 70
kilometers in altitude. Fairly quickly after a violent breakup, pieces
cool down and the trajectory becomes nearly vertical as the objects'
forward velocity rapidly decreases. There is no difference in the size
of debris that passes through navigable airspace and debris that
strikes the ground.
The Aerospace technical report estimated that Starlink spacecraft
could create three objects each that could cause an aircraft downing
incident.
Since over 85 percent of the expected 2035 risk to people on the
ground and aviation from reentering debris is a result of FAA licensed
launches of Starlink satellites, it would be worthwhile to
definitively evaluate if any debris from random atmospheric reentry of
Starlink spacecraft survives reentry.

Cockpit windows are bird-proof at approach speeds, but that's different from metal fragments at cruising speed.
The Space Force has used scheduled deorbiting of Starlinks to practice Space Domain Awareness with real-world events https://www.airandspaceforces.com/spacex-space-force-deorbiting-opportunity . Has this generated real-world data on the fragments' size and depth of penetration?

Another potential data source would be ground-based weather Doppler radars.  I don't have a source handy, but my reasoning:  thunderstorm tops for strong storms get way up into the top of the stratosphere, above airliner cruise height.  So the useful data envelope for weather radars will almost certainly see re-entering Starlink debris if they're actually making it down to airliner height. Unfortunately you probably have to have a lot of metadata in addition to raw radar data to decide if the radar was set in such a way that it would filter those out or not.

"it would be worthwhile to definitively evaluate" does not mean it does, it means that they would like to be more confident that it doesn't.

EDIT: The initial question was "Are de-orbiting Starlink satellites a danger to commercial airliners?". The entire section about the FAA disagreeing with SpaceX's assessment was added later.
Modified answer in light of the additions to the question:
In an August 10, 2021 letter to the FCC, SpaceX stated that “v1.0 Starlink satellites are designed to be fully demisable” and “[p]ose zero Risk of Human Casualty.” (page 22 of the report)
The FAA report was published in 2023.

SpaceX used the NASA program Debris Assessment Software (DAS). DAS is the standard evaluation tool used to assess the ground risk of reentry. A more sophisticated analysis tool is also available from NASA. The Object Reentry Survival Analysis Tool (ORSAT) provides a higher fidelity modeling software to evaluate demisability.
FCC regulations do not require the use of ORSAT or DAS – CFR 47 § 25.114 Applications for space station authorizations.

Both SpaceX and FAA statements are based on models, rather than practical experience.
In a letter from October 2023, SpaceX disagrees with the FAA report. Their letter states:

SpaceX has already deorbited 325 of its satellites since January 2020 with zero pieces of debris found.

The letter also questions the accuracy of the FAA evaluation.

FAA's report relies exclusively on a technical evaluation conducted in 2021 by the Aerospace Corporation...


Aerospace did not even seek to review the Starlink demisability analysis...


Aerospace based its analysis on a generalization from a 23-year-old NASA study that specifically warns against using it in that way. Here, the NASA study from 2000 found that roughly one piece of debris survives reentry for every 100 kg on Iridium satellites. This analysis is inapplicable to SpaceX satellites because - among other things- Iridium satellites were not even built to be fully demisable.


"Demisable" is a word of questionable utility since the only dictionary definition is as a legal term meaning "leasable". It comes from the root "demise" meaning "death". So presumably SpaceX is using it as in "Starlink satellites can die". This qualifies as obfuscation, better known as a  "weasel word".

The FCC filing contains 3+ pages just on the topic of Atmospheric Demise alone, and another 4+ pages on Orbital Debris, nominal and abnormal Deorbit Procedures, and an analysis of the worst-case failure modes of a satellite breaking up and/or completely becoming uncontrollable.

Dragon Trunk was also supposed to be fully demisable, then eventually large pieces landed and were found

@Woody No, atmospheric demise is a term used by satellite engineers before SpaceX existed. It is a "term of art". Reference from 1997.

@user71659 .... "term of art" is yet another legal weasel word: " = words or expressions that have through usage by legal professionals acquired a distinct legal meaning". Lawyers speak obfuscative legalese. The rest of us speak English as found in dictionaries. When addressing a general audience, SpaceX would do better to speak English.

It seems to pretty clearly be an argument between the FAA and SpaceX. The FAA has stated: Starlink spacecraft could create three objects each that could cause an aircraft downing incident, while SpaceX has stated: Starlink satellites are also fully demisable by design, meaning that the risk to those on the ground, in the air, or at sea from a deorbiting satellite is effectively zero. These are fundamentally irreconcilable viewpoints.

@Woody But they're not addressing a general audience, they're addressing regulators. The terms they use are specifically chosen to communicate, to other people "in the know", exactly what they can and cannot promise. If we lay people are confused by it, that's not their problem.

@Woody are you seriously coming to an aerospace technology forum & arguing against the invention of new precisely-defined jargon

@Cadence ...   I have no objection to the appropriate use of technical terminology. It is essential for technical communication. I object to the use of obscure terminology when addressing the public, as in the use of  "demisable" in this SpaceX PR release https://www.spacex.com/updates
